# Python Wifi Breaks Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wifi

I am currently building an application on Raspberry Pi using Python, and I am trying to connect to the wifi. The package I am using is [wifi](https://pypi.org/project/wifi/) 0.3.8 installed via pip3.

The code looks like this for connecting:

```
    cell = wifi.Scheme.find('wlan0', ssid)
    scheme = wifi.Scheme.for_cell('wlan0', cell.ssid, cell, password)
    scheme.save()
    scheme.activate()
```

There are several problems I've encountered:

**Uses ifup and ifdown**

The current problem with the package is it uses **/sbin/ifup** and **/sbin/ifdown**. These are deprecated and do not work. My hack fix was to reroute to use **/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 up** and **/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down**. Yes very hacky but it worked.

**Modifies /etc/network/interfaces**

The biggest problem I've encountered is modified **/etc/network/interfaces** by placing a connection string in there with something like:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

uface wlan0-[network-ssid-name]
```

Which breaks the wifi completely. I've had to re-type the entire configuration file to get it working again. It SHOULD be modifying **/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf** only.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to correctly connect to the wifi using Python?

Comment: Why would you want to connect to WiFi using Python? Surely you would just configure your system to boot with working WiFi every time.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm building an application on a microdevice, and it needs to allow the user, that has not currently logged into a wifi network. to select a Wifi network within the application.